# Used 'Routes' instead of 'Switch' but app is disappeared? how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Used 'Routes' instead of 'Switch' but app is disappeared, when deleting the routes and other react-router-dom properties then it's rendering.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
```

```
<Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <Alert/>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <TextForm/>
          </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the element specification:

```
    <Router>
        <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={
                    <>
                        <TextForm />
                    </>
                }
                ></Route>
                <Route path='/about' element={ <AboutPage />}/>
            </Routes>
    </Router>
```